# How do I create a datetime from a custom format string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have datetime values stored in a field as strings. They are stored as strings because that's how they come across the wire and the raw values are used in other places.

For reporting, I want to convert the custom format string (yyyymmddhhmm) to a datetime field in a view. My reports will use the view and work with real datetime values. This will make queries involving date ranges much easier.

How do I perform this conversion? I created the view but can't find a way to convert the string to a datetime.

Thanks!

Update 1 -

Here's the SQL I have so far. When I try to execute, I get a conversion error "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

How do I handle nulls and datetime strings that are missing the time portion (just yyyymmdd)?

```
SELECT  
        dbo.PV1_B.PV1_F44_C1 AS ArrivalDT,

cast(substring(dbo.PV1_B.PV1_F44_C1, 1, 8)+' '+substring(dbo.PV1_B.PV1_F44_C1, 9, 2)+':'+substring(dbo.PV1_B.PV1_F44_C1, 11, 2) as datetime) AS ArrDT,

        dbo.MSH_A.MSH_F9_C2 AS MessageType,
        dbo.PID_A.PID_F3_C1 AS PRC,
        dbo.PID_A.PID_F5_C1 AS LastName, 
        dbo.PID_A.PID_F5_C2 AS FirstName,
        dbo.PID_A.PID_F5_C3 AS MiddleInitial,
        dbo.PV1_A.PV1_F2_C1 AS Score, 
        dbo.MSH_A.MessageID AS MessageId

FROM    dbo.MSH_A
        INNER JOIN dbo.PID_A ON dbo.MSH_A.MessageID = dbo.PID_A.MessageID
        INNER JOIN dbo.PV1_A ON dbo.MSH_A.MessageID = dbo.PV1_A.MessageID
        INNER JOIN dbo.PV1_B ON dbo.MSH_A.MessageID = dbo.PV1_B.MessageID
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle NULLs"? Do you want to return the rows with a NULL value, or leave them out? What about invalid strings (e.g. 20110101333333)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @S varchar(12)
set @S = '201107062114'

select cast(substring(@S, 1, 8)+' '+substring(@S, 9, 2)+':'+substring(@S, 11, 2) as datetime)
```

Result:

```
2011-07-06 21:14:00.000'
```

This first changes your date string to `20110706 21:14`. Date format yyyymmdd as a string is safe to convert to datetime in SQL Server regardless of [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) setting.

Edit:

```
declare @T table(S varchar(12))

insert into @T values('201107062114')
insert into @T values('20110706')
insert into @T values(null)

select 
  case len(S)
    when 12 then cast(substring(S, 1, 8)+' '+substring(S, 9, 2)+':'+substring(S, 11, 2) as datetime)
    when 8 then cast(S as datetime)
  end   
from @T
```

Result:

```
2011-07-06 21:14:00.000
2011-07-06 00:00:00.000
NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), there's no out-of-the-box `CONVERT` to get from your `yyyymmddhhmm` format to datetime.

Your strategy will be parsing the string to one of the formats provided on the documentation, then convert it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Example from the site:

> G. Using CAST and CONVERT with
>   datetime data
>
> The following example displays the
>   current date and time, uses CAST to
>   change the current date and time to a
>   character data type, and then uses
>   CONVERT display the date and time in
>   the ISO 8901 format.
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>    GETDATE() AS UnconvertedDateTime,
>    CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)) AS UsingCast,
>    CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601;
> GO
> ```
>
> Here is the result set.
>
> ```
> UnconvertedDateTime     UsingCast                      UsingConvertTo_ISO8601
>
> ----------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
>
> 2006-04-18 09:58:04.570 Apr 18 2006 9:58AM             2006-04-18T09:58:04.570
>
>
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use this code:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'20110706',112)
```

If you need to force SQL Server to use a custom format string, use the following code:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd

SELECT convert(datetime,'20110706')
```

Comment: `select convert(datetime, '201101230555',112)` does not work. OP has a specific format.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(12);

SET @d = '201101011235';

SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(@d,9,0,' '),12,0,':'));
```

Note that by storing date/time data using an inappropriate data type, you cannot prevent bad data from ending up in here. So it might be safer to do this:

```
WITH x(d) AS
(
    SELECT d = '201101011235'
        UNION SELECT '201101011267' -- not valid
        UNION SELECT NULL -- NULL
        UNION SELECT '20110101' -- yyyymmdd only
),
y(d, dt) AS 
(
    SELECT d,
        dt = STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(d+'000000',12),9,0,' '),12,0,':')
    FROM x
)
SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, dt), ''
    FROM y
    WHERE ISDATE(dt) = 1 OR d IS NULL
UNION
SELECT NULL, d
    FROM y
    WHERE ISDATE(dt) = 0 AND d IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
declare @datestring varchar(255)
set @datestring = '201102281723'

select convert(datetime, stuff(stuff(@datestring,9,0,' '),12,0,':') , 112 )
```

Result:

```
2011-02-28 17:23:00.000
```

Answer (score -3):

```
DECLARE @test varchar(100) = '201104050800'
DECLARE @dt smalldatetime

SELECT @dt = SUBSTRING(@test, 5, 2) 
             + '/' + SUBSTRING(@test, 7, 2) + '/' 
             + SUBSTRING(@test, 1, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@test, 9, 2) 
             + ':' + SUBSTRING(@test, 11, 2)

SELECT @dt
```

Output:

`2011-04-05 08:00:00`