# sql-server: Convert Char(14) to Datetime?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

With SQL-server 2008 database I have a `char(14)` data type that I want to convert to a datetime.

Example char(14) values:

```
20120209102026
20010131120000
```

The date format is `yyyymmdd` of some sort.

It seems like the values I posted are not the only format, because I get an "index out of range" error for some of the values.  For this I can skip the ones that are not valid dates.

Comment: Actually it looks like `yyyyMMddhhmmss`. What version of SQL Server are you using? Can you use SQL CLR?

Comment: I am using sql 2008. I think the database was originally sql server 2000 that is in some sort of compatibility mode.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601663/how-do-i-create-a-datetime-from-a-custom-format-string

Comment: @chobo2 here datetime is stored as `string` so there should be a format `defined`. Otherwise hit and trial with possible format would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @c char(14)
select @c='20120209102026'

Select Cast(Substring(@c,1,8) + ' ' + Substring(@c,9,2)+':'+ 
    Substring(@c,11,2)+':'+ Substring(@c,13,2) as DateTime)
```

Second Version that ignores out of range numeric values:

```
Select Cast( 
Rtrim(Substring(@c,1,8) 
+ Case When len(Substring(@c,9,4))>=4 then +' '+ Substring(@c,9,2) else '' end
+ Case When len(Substring(@c,11,2))=2 then +':'+ Substring(@c,11,2) else '' end
+ Case When len(Substring(@c,13,2))=2 then +':'+ Substring(@c,13,2) else '' end)
as Datetime)
```

Comment: hmm you know what. I think they have different formats stored in this table as I am getting a index out of range.

Comment: what about selecting these by e.g. WHERE NOT ISDATE(constructAbove)

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but if your format is `yyyymmddhhmmss` then you can use:

```
select cast(left(yourDate, 8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING(yourDate, 9, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(yourDate, 11, 2)+':'+RIGHT(yourDate, 2) as datetime)
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e32b3/2)

Comment: @Beth I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: thought it needed to be yyyy/mm/dd, but apparently, the cast works without the /s

Comment: @Beth Actually, `yyyyMMdd` is the safer way to store dates as chars, as is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

A series of function calls but ends up with the same outcome.

Try like this:

```
select convert(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20010131120000',5,0,'/'),8,0,'/'),11,0,' '),14,0,':'),17,0,':'))
```

Look here for how [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) works!